# Python encoding/decoding problem in armv71 Linux

Tags: python, character-encoding, decoding

I wrote some Python codes in my e-Book reader device, and cannot solve encoding/decoding problem.
My environment is below:

- Device: Kobo Aura One
- OS: Linux (none) 3.0.35+ #5030 PREEMPT Wed Oct 25 10:25:24 CST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
- Python 3.4.1

Test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import locale

# Check the encoding and locale.
print('stderr:', sys.stderr, 'stdout:', sys.stdout)
print('filesystem encoding:', sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print('default locale:', locale.getdefaultlocale())
print('preferred encoding:', locale.getpreferredencoding())

path = '/mnt/onboard/Library'
for sub in os.listdir(path):
  print(sub)
```

There are some non-alphabet named files(Korean) in "path". Alphabet-named files are printed normally, but non-alphabet-named files occur exceptions.

Result:

```
stderr: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'> stdout: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
filesystem encoding: ascii
default locale: (None, None)
preferred encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./total.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(sub)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, I tried to set environments,

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING='UTF-8'
export LANG='C.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'
```

Result:

```
stderr: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> stdout: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
filesystem encoding: ascii
default locale: ('C', 'UTF-8')
preferred encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./total.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(sub)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udced' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

This time, I modified code and file names printed well.

```
    print(sub.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').decode('utf-8'))
```

But, I met another problem. I couldn't access those files. For example, add a line,

```
    print(os.path.exists(sub))
```

Result, False.
Several alternatives were same or caused exceptions.

```
print(os.path.exists(sub))                                                     # False
print(os.path.exists(sub.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').decode('utf-8')))  # False
print(os.path.exists(sub.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape')))                  # False
print(os.path.exists(sub.encode('ascii'))                                      # Exception
print(os.path.exists(sub.encode('ascii').decode('ascii')))                     # Exception
print(os.path.exists(sub.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').decode('ascii')))  # Exception
```

Now, I have no idea.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Result, False. Several alternatives were same or caused exceptions.

When you you re-encode `sub` you're effectively changing the value even if it "looks" the same. The path returned by `os.listdir` will not be the same value when you re-encode using the UTF-8 and ignore options.

If you want to display the filename and also access its contents you'll need to store both values.

> `print(os.path.exists(sub))`
>
> `# False`

Try `os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, sub))`.

Comment: Oh, my mistakes. I misunderstood that listdir() returns the full path of the file, but only returns file name. I spent two days.... Thanks.

Comment: I usually work with higher versions and os.scandir(), but in this envrionment, python 3.4 not suports scandir(). I didn't know return value of listdir().